# Triangular wave graphed instead of Sin wave in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, trigonometry

I am designing composite sin wave such as

`input=sin(2*pi*Fm_1*t) + sin(2*pi*Fm_2*t);`

where Fm_1, and Fm_2 are given by the user and

```
t=0:Ts:2*Tm;
```

where

```
Ts=1/Fs;
Tm=1/(maxof(Fm_1,Fm_2) (NOT A FUNCTION, just to explain)
```

and `Fm_1 = 5`and `Fm_2 = 10` and `Fs = 30`
and plot using `plot(t,input);`

Now for some reason, the output is correct but instead of being a sine wave, it's a triangular wave (straight lines). Other than that, the output is correct.

**EDIT:**

I just found out that because I plotted two graphs on the same scale, an error in the second graph screwed up the first.

Now the problem is filtering the input using  this :

```
  output = filtfilt(B,A,input);
```

Why does this give me nothing when I plot it (I also tried using `filter`)?

Comment: Your `Fs` might be small. Increase it and retry. Is it again a triangular wave?

Comment: I retried using Fs=300 .. The plot changed entirelly. became a horizontal line

Comment: I can send you the whole code to look at, maybe i am missing something and i didnt include in the question, but its too big

Comment: Your `Ts` should be very small to make your plots smooth.

Comment: Fs = 2Fm.. Nyquist thereom.. How can it work being to small

Comment: You don't need to put it as step size in your plot. Just use `t=linspace(0,2*Tm,1000);` and see what happens. Does it work?

Comment: well.. it worked it became an actual curvy wave but not sine wave .. :S

Comment: Sum of two sine waves at different frequencies is not going to be another sinewave.

Comment: Its gonna be a composite sinewave..I mean not an actual sine wave but still curvy.not triangular

Comment: @user1111726 If you have a _new_ question, please post it separately. Don't change the existing post to include both questions, otherwise it makes it much more difficult to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the problem is that you're using a way too low sampling frequency to plot a detailed graph. You can see this using the function below:

```
function myplot(Fm_1, Fm_2, Fs)
  Ts = 1/Fs;
  Tm = 1/max(Fm_1,Fm_2);
  t = 0:Ts:2*Tm;
  input = sin(2*pi*Fm_1*t) + sin(2*pi*Fm_2*t);
  plot(t, input);
end
```

As you noticed, for `Fs = 30` you get a plot like this:

[image]

Increasing to `Fs = 100`, the situation improves:

[image]

And for `Fs = 1000` the plot is what you'd probably expect in the first place:

[image]

Note that for all the above I've used the values `Fm_1 = 5` and `Fm_2 = 10` that you provided.

Comment: for some reason.. increasing the sampling frequency changes the plot completely.. the plot becomes a horizontal line

Comment: I using MATLAB 7.. could that be a reason for this fault ?

Comment: Ok .. I just found out .. that beacause I plotted two graphs on the same scale.. and as the second graph is wrong it screwd up the first..PLease see edit